# How to get previous 10 days post from a specific date - WP Query

Tags: posts, wp-query, query-posts, get-posts

I want to know how to get previous 10 days post from a specific date, as I know that it can be done from current date as below

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'date_query'    => array(
        'after'   => '- 10 days'
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

But I want posts previous 10 days post from a **specific date**. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can pass full date as before and after params, so:

```
$given_date_as_time = strtotime('2017-11-22 00:00:00');
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'date_query' => array(
        'before' => date( 'c', $given_date_as_time ),
        'after' => date('c', strtotime( '- 10 days', $given_date_as_time ) ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

above query is also correct and will give you result you wanted.

Comment: Great, that worked for me. I am getting time in milliseconds, so directly using milliseconds is not working for me. Like ** 'before' => date( 'c', '1532995200000' )**

Comment: You should pass miliseconds as integer and not as string... And it should be timestamp (as result of `time()` function) and not miliseconds, I guess...